# How to show all categories in MediaWiki Main or other pages?

Tags: mediawiki, mediawiki-extensions

I want to display all the categories in main page or any other page in MediaWiki just like how it displays in Special:Categories page.

Any help is appreciated.

Comment: Why not use Extension:CategoryTree?

Comment: I read about the extension .. i can see that it is used to visualise the structure of the categories. For example : <categorytree mode=pages>Manual</categorytree> . This syntax is used to display the category structure of Manual category. What i want is like i want to display all the categories in my wiki. Is it possible thru Extenion:CategoryTree?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

The only built-in ways to display all categories are the special pages `Special:Categories` and `Special:AllPages` (in a default MediaWiki setup the categories are in NS 14, so `Special:AllPages?namespace=14`). Of those two, AllPages is [transcludible](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Wikipedia:Transclusion#Special_pages), meaning that you can do like this on your main page:

```
{{Special:AllPages|namespace=14}}
```

If you want more control over the output, I suggest you use an extension like [Semantic MediaWiki](https://www.mediawiki.org/wiki/Extension:Semantic_MediaWiki) (advanced, full control), or [CategoryTree](https://www.mediawiki.org/wiki/Extension:CategoryTree) (but as you noted, you will have to organize your category in a tree structure, with a common root).

Comment: That `{{Special:AllPages|namespace=14}}` is just what I was looking for!

Comment: According to the page to linked to, `{{Special:Prefixindex/Category:}}` should do the same, but the list doesn't include the `Category:` prefix for each entry.